# mysql query where conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database, here are the columns;

*date*

*computerlab*

*period*

---

Only 2 possible data values go into the computerlab column, A101 or A102

However, there can be duplicate rows of data but with different computerlab data

For example,

date = 3-15-16   computerlab = A101   period = 1

date = 3-15-16   computerlab = A102   period = 1

---

My webpage gets input from the user receiving several periods 1,3,5

This is what I need:

If period 1 or 3 or 5 contains both A101 and A102 then return that date

---

I would think this would work but it doesn't

```
mysql_query("SELECT date FROM reservations WHERE period IN ($periods) AND lab in ('A101','A102') GROUP BY date HAVING COUNT(*) = 2");
```

Comment: Do you use certain framework ?

Comment: `but it doesn't`, what happens, no results? error?

Comment: no results, but now I have the answer, below. thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to group by both period *and* date to get what you want:

```
SELECT date, period
FROM reservations
WHERE period IN ($periods) AND lab in ('A101', 'A102')
GROUP BY period, date
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

This will check that a given period has both labs.  You were checking that the set of three periods had exactly two entries.

Hmmm, I realize that you might intend to check if the three periods had both labs assigned, in any combination.  If so then use `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT date
FROM reservations
WHERE period IN ($periods) AND lab in ('A101', 'A102')
GROUP BY date
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT lab) = 2;
```

Comment: Yes this worked, thanks I'll make it the correct answer in a few minutes. Both worked fine